# Using BatchNorm1d layer with Embedding and Linear layers for NLP text-classification problem throws RuntimeError

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization, torchtext

I am trying to create a neural network and train my own Embeddings. The network has the following structure (PyTorch):

```py
import torch.nn as nn

class MultiClassClassifer(nn.Module):
  #define all the layers used in model
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
    
    #Constructor
    super(MultiClassClassifer, self).__init__()

    #embedding layer
    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

    #dense layer
    self.hiddenLayer = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)

    #Batch normalization layer
    self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dim)

    #output layer
    self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    #activation layer
    self.act = nn.Softmax(dim=1) #2d-tensor

    #initialize weights of embedding layer
    self.init_weights()

  def init_weights(self):

    initrange = 1.0
    
    self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
  
  def forward(self, text):

    embedded = self.embedding(text)

    hidden_1 = self.batchnorm(self.hiddenLayer(embedded))

    return self.act(self.output(hidden_1))
```

My training_iterator object looks like:

```
 batch = next(iter(train_iterator))
 batch.text_normalized_tweet[0]
```

```
tensor([[ 240,  538,  305,   73,    9,  780, 2038,   13,   48,    1,    1,    1,
            1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1],
        [ 853,   57,    2,   70, 1875,  176,  466,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,
            1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1],
        ...])
```

with shape: `torch.Size([32, 25])`. 32= batch_size I used to create the training iterator with `data.BucketIterator` and 25 = the sequences in the batch.

When I create a model instance:

```
INPUT_DIM = len(TEXT.vocab) #~5,000 tokens
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
HIDDEN_DIM = 64
OUTPUT_DIM = 3 #target has 3 classes

model = MultiClassClassifer(INPUT_DIM, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
```

and execute

```
model(batch.text_normalized_tweet[0]).squeeze(1)
```

I get back the following `RuntimeError`

> RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 15 elements not 64

You may also find my Golab Notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HtohSU4oz_FwllYll0WgVtbaj4cI-FR2?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround based on the example given by @jhso ([above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70356610/10623444)).

```
INPUT_DIM = len(TEXT.vocab) #~5,000 tokens
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
HIDDEN_DIM = 64

e = nn.Embedding(INPUT_DIM, EMBEDDING_DIM)
l = nn.Linear(EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM)
b = nn.BatchNorm1d(HIDDEN_DIM)
soft = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
out = nn.Linear(HIDDEN_DIM, 3)

text, text_lengths = batch.text_normalized_tweet
y = e(text)
tensor, batch_size = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(y,text_lengths, batch_first=True)[0], nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(y,text_lengths, batch_first=True)[1] #added rnn.pack_padded_sequence
y = b(l(tensor))
```

Added `pack_padded_sequence()` method from `utils.rnn` package which will take the embeddings as input. I also had to calculate both the *text* and the *text_lengths* since the way I created the training_iteror it returns 2 outputs (text, text_lenght).

Answer (score 0):

The output of your embedding layer is [batch, seqlen, F], and you can see in the docs for batchnorm1d that you need to have an input of shape [batch, F, seqlen]. You should change transpose this to get the desired output size:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class MultiClassClassifer(nn.Module):
  #define all the layers used in model
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
    
    #Constructor
    super(MultiClassClassifer, self).__init__()

    #embedding layer
    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

    #dense layer
    self.hiddenLayer = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)

    #Batch normalization layer
    self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dim)

    #output layer
    self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    #activation layer
    self.act = nn.Softmax(dim=1) #2d-tensor

    #initialize weights of embedding layer
    self.init_weights()

  def init_weights(self):

    initrange = 1.0
    
    self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
  
  def forward(self, text):

    embedded = self.embedding(text)

    embedded_T = embedded.transpose(1,2)

    hidden_1 = self.batchnorm(self.hiddenLayer(embedded_T))

    return self.act(self.output(hidden_1))
```

Comment: PS. Your softmax will then need to be changed too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jhso. When I try to execute your script I receive back this ```RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1000x15 and 100x64)```. Should I expect that?

Comment: Sorry, left a hardcoded value in there. Should work now.

Comment: May I ask you what is the purpose of value 10 in [10, Embedding dim]. Thanks

Comment: it's just a batch size, it's meaningless in the context of solving your problem

Comment: Running your script in a colab notebook it returns ```RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 100 elements not 64```

Comment: Are you sure? I've applied the batch norm layer to the output of the linear layer, which is of size 64...

Comment: Could you please publish a colab notebook with a runnable example of your solution? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know why you're having problems so I just edited my answer. All you need to do is transpose the outputs of your embedding layer.